# AlertDialog: Margin on top

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-alertdialog

My AlertDialog is displayed with extra margin on top, without me declaring it.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;    

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.act);
builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_progress);
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
builder.create().show();
```

dialog_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:orientation="horizontal">

   <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/TextView.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/fetching_location"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

The other dialogs of my app look just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for some hours I finally found out why my dialog is laid out so weird:

AndroidStudio imported AlertDialog from the package `android.support.v7.app`. The other dialogs I use in my app were imported from the package `android.app`. After changing the import everything looked fine:

[image]
(Changed the gravity and added some slight padding)

Maybe this will help everybody having the same problem.

Comment: The problem is that these Dialogs won't look like that on <= API19, so you actually need the compatibility dialog for them. Too bad they add the weirdly looking padding. Maybe this has something to do with paddingCompat, like with the FAB? So this does not really solve the problem, since I introduced the compat dialogs to my app for compatiblity in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use windowNoTitle:

1. Create style for the AlertDialog:

```
    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@000000</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

2. Define this style while creating AlertDialog

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(container.getContext(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom);